# if/else in list comprehension for python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

- `current_user` is a `list`
- `new_user` is another `list`
- Code is meant to compare the list against each other and filter out any repeated usernames.

```
count = 0
users = new_user[count]
[print(f'{users} user name taken'), count +1 if users == current_users else count+1 for users in current_user]

returns an error
```

Mind you I am a beginner currently self-studying please explain in a way that someone starting out might understand.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: Always tag your questions with the programming language you are using; that will ensure they are seen by the most people.

Comment: Why are you printing inside a list comprehension? A print statement will return `None`, so you're just filling your list with `None` values. Additionally, the `, count +1` will cause an error, since it appears you're defining a tuple of `None` and some counted value, but there's no parentheses around the tuple. What do you hope to achieve with the comprehension? Why are you using a comprehension for what appears to be more suited to a normal loop?

Comment: Sets are often used for this task. `set(current_user + new_user)` would combine the lists and remove duplicates. BTW, those are odd names for collections. Maybe "current_users" and "new_users"?

Comment: @Grismar what is a none value? What is a list comprehension more suited to do?

Comment: What was the actual error?

Comment: @deluis You should only use a list comprehension when the intention of your code is to actually build a list. Otherwise, use a regular for loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. You need a [mre] and debugging details also. Anyway, you should learn the basics of the ```list```, ```for``` loop, etc, at first. Also see [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). For example, ```for users in current_user``` in your code is a nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Errors caused by:

- `current_users` should be `current_user`
- `print(f'{users} user name taken'), count +1` should be in
  parentheses

When it get fixed:

- You might think `users` in list comprehension is `new_user[count]`, it's
  actually not.
- `if users == current_users` is always `False`. Even though you change it
  with `in`, the output might not as you expected.
- `count = 0`, `users = new_user[count]`, and `count +1`  is
  unnecessary

A straightforward way would be iterate over `new_user` and check if its element in `current_user` then print it:

```
current_user = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
new_user = ['b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h']

[print(f'{users} user name taken') for users in new_user if users in current_user]
```

Or normal for loop:

```
current_user = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
new_user = ['b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h']

for user in new_user:
    if user in current_user:
        print(f'{user} user name taken')
```

Output:

```
b user name taken
d user name taken
```

Comment: Answering a useless question like this(in its current state) is not useful to others. What about letting the OP edit the question?